# R agrep() function behaviour

Tags: r, string-matching, agrep

I have some trouble to understand the result of `agrep()` function. I don't understand what I have missed in the description of the function.
`agrep()` is for fuzzy matching and I'd like to use it to correct some misspelling. I'd like to allow only a maximum of 2 insertions / deletions / substitutions.

Here is my code just for an example:

```
check=c("73SAINTGERMAINLACHAMBOTTE","73CHAMBERY")
agrep("73SAINTGERVAIS",check,ignore.case=TRUE,max.distance=2,value=TRUE)
```

Here, what I expect is to have no answer for this request because I can't transform `"73SAINTGERVAIS"` into `"73SAINTGERMAINLACHAMBOTTE"` or `"73CHAMBERY"` with a maximum of 2 insertions / deletions / substitutions.
However, the result is :

```
[1] "73SAINTGERMAINLACHAMBOTTE"
```

Does it mean that the notion of insertions / deletions / substitutions isn't character-based (I mean the string `"MAINLACHALBOTTE"` is considered as 1 insertion)?

Comment: ok thanks, I didn't understand the "within" notion, that's clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because it is doing partial matching as well. For example, `'73SAINTGERVAIS'` is two distance away from the substring `'73SAINTGERMAIN'`.

You may want to try `adist` instead like this:

```
check=c("73SAINTGERMAINLACHAMBOTTE","73CHAMBERY", "73SAINTGERMAIN")
adist("73SAINTGERVAIS",check) <= 2
      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

If you want the vector of matched input strings as output, you can further do the following:

```
check[as.logical(adist("73SAINTGERVAIS",check) <= 2)]
```